# Anxiously looking over my shoulder for a [backstab]

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently [37 questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=backstab%20is%3aquestion) which specifically mention backstab connectors, and given that there are [over 400 answers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=backstab%20is%3aanswer) using the word "backstab," there are probably many more questions which would qualify for this tag, but the askers didn't know the terminology.

As we're well aware, the common advice is not to use backstab connectors, but in looking through the answers there doesn't seem to be any canonical source for this. Given that backstab connections are (or at least were) UL certified, it would seem important to make a strong case against their use.

I propose we create [backstab](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backstab) and include some canonical references in the tag wiki providing data about the risks of this connection type.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I've created the tag. I doubt askers will ever use it, but it will be edited into questions later. We'll see if the creation is approved. (Odd, I have the privilege of reviewing tag edits, but not the privilege of making a new tag...)

Answer (score 5):

I think this is too much of a [Meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Let's consider

1. This is a colloquialism. [We have a question that has to define the term](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/201207/55930). We shouldn't expect new users to know the colloquial term. [Leviton calls it Quickwire](https://store.leviton.com/products/15-amp-125-volt-duplex-receptacle-residential-grade-self-grounding-brown-ivory-light-almond-white-5320-s?variant=18216350915). [Legrand doesn't even mention it](https://www.legrand.us/wiring-devices/outlets-and-receptacles/residential-receptacles/15a-125v-trademaster-duplex-receptacle-brown/p/3232w).
2. [Half the backstab mentions are from Harper](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=backstab+is%3Aanswer+user%3A47125) (he rants about them a lot).
3. Not all of those mentions warrant the tag. Only three questions mention it in the title (which means it's the topic of the question, which is what tags are for). I fear the tag will be slapped on anything that merely mentions backstabs

I would definitely like to see some canonicals for the subject, tho. We do need folks to understand why these are a bad idea

Comment: 1/2. Some good points. 1) Being a colloquialism is an argument for synonyms. If I'm reading UL 498 section 12.6 correctly, the proper term is "spring action clamp terminal." 2) Not sure having an expert (or expert ranter) on a topic should disqualify it from being a tag. 3) Agreed -- but for any question where it's the topic or a key part of the question, the tag should apply.

Comment: 2/2. I read that blog post from Joel, and I don't think this tag meets those criteria: a question with the tag could stand by itself (I'd argue that the example question you link is one such case), and if we use the UL definition, then it's clear the tag applies to one specific, objective thing.